Apache FOP/Xmlgraphics can't load SVG if it is in a jar
I've got an application using Apache FOP to create a PDF which includes an SVG image (it's a logo and is the same every time)
I find that it doesn't include the image if I use Maven's assembly plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies.
I did some work to narrow it down and it seems that the SVG image loader isn't registered when the application is in a jar - so it's not the PDF part of FOP as such, it's the ImageManager which is in xmlgraphics-commons.
I've pasted in a minimal example below, it will need files called img.png, img.tiff and img.svg in the current directory.
If you run this with mvn exec:java it prints out
image (image/png)
image (image/tiff)
image (image/svg+xml)

and if you run mvn package and then java -cp .\target\mavenproject2-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar project.Mavenproject2 you get
image (image/png)
image (image/tiff)
Nov 26, 2024 10:19:15 AM project.Mavenproject2 load
SEVERE: Loading img.svg
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException: The file format is not supported. No ImagePreloader found for image
        at org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager.preloadImage(ImageManager.java:181)
        at project.Mavenproject2.load(Mavenproject2.java:43)
        at project.Mavenproject2.main(Mavenproject2.java:31)

null

So the SVG loader is not available.
Is there a way to tell FOP to register that SVG loader or it impossible to run it from a jar with dependencies and I should look to package the application some other way?
Minimal example code:
package project;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactoryBuilder;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageException;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageInfo;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageManager;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.ImageSource;

public class Mavenproject2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, ImageException, IOException {
        Mavenproject2 me = new Mavenproject2();
        System.out.println(me.load("img.png"));
        System.out.println(me.load("img.tiff"));
        System.out.println(me.load("img.svg"));
    }

    public Mavenproject2() {
        URI base = URI.create("https://example.com/nowhere");
        FopFactoryBuilder ffb = new FopFactoryBuilder(base);
        this.imageManager = ffb.getImageManager();
    }
    private final ImageManager imageManager;

    public ImageInfo load(String ff) {
        try {
            File sourceFile = new File(ff);
            ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(sourceFile);
            ImageInfo preloadImage = imageManager.preloadImage("image", new ImageSource(iis, "image", true));
            return preloadImage;
        } catch (IOException | ImageException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Mavenproject2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Loading " + ff, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }
}


and the POM:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
            <artifactId>fop</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>21</maven.compiler.release>
        <exec.mainClass>project.Mavenproject2</exec.mainClass>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptorRefs>
                                jar-with-dependencies
                            </descriptorRefs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Using maven 3.9.9 on Windows11.
[edit] Logging as requested by @francesco-poli
When not in a jar (and it works)
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderTIFF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderGIF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderJPEG with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderBMP with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEMF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEPS with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.PreloaderImageIO with priority 2000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderRawPNG with priority 2000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderWMF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/png, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/vnd.wap.wbmp, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/vnd.wap.wbmp, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/x-png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/x-png, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/bmp, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/bmp, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/gif, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/gif, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/png, Flavor = image/png;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = image/jpeg;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = image/tiff;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/x-emf, Flavor = image/x-emf;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRawCCITTFax: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RawCCITTFax
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryEPS: MIME = application/postscript, Flavor = application/postscript;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryInternalTIFF: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryPNG: MIME = image/png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.ImageLoaderFactorySVG: MIME = image/svg+xml, Flavor = text/xml;DOM;namespace=http://www.w3.org/2000/svg
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.ImageLoaderFactoryWMF: MIME = image/x-wmf, Flavor = WMFRecordStore
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterBuffered2Rendered
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterG2D2Bitmap
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterBitmap2G2D
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterRendered2PNG
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.ImageConverterSVG2G2D
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.ImageConverterG2D2SVG
Nov 26, 2024 12:34:44 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.ImageConverterWMF2G2D

When in a jar (and doesn't work)
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderTIFF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderGIF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderJPEG with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderBMP with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEMF with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEPS with priority 1000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.PreloaderImageIO with priority 2000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerPreloader
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderRawPNG with priority 2000
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/png, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/vnd.wap.wbmp, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/vnd.wap.wbmp, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/x-png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/x-png, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/bmp, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/bmp, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/gif, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.ImageLoaderFactoryImageIO: MIME = image/gif, Flavor = BufferedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/png, Flavor = image/png;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/jpeg, Flavor = image/jpeg;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = image/tiff;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRaw: MIME = image/x-emf, Flavor = image/x-emf;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryRawCCITTFax: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RawCCITTFax
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryEPS: MIME = application/postscript, Flavor = application/postscript;Raw
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryInternalTIFF: MIME = image/tiff, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerLoaderFactory
FINE: Registered org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageLoaderFactoryPNG: MIME = image/png, Flavor = RenderedImage
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterBuffered2Rendered
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterG2D2Bitmap
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterBitmap2G2D
Nov 26, 2024 12:37:49 PM org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageImplRegistry registerConverter
FINE: Registered: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageConverterRendered2PNG

[edit2]
Might be onto something. The image preloaders are identified using xmlgraphics org.apache.xmlgraphics.util.Service class which scans through files in the META-INF.services dir within the jar.
In fop-core.jar/META-INF/services/org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImagePreloader  is:
org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderWMF
org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG

and in xmlgraphics-commons-2.10.jar/META-INF/services/org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImagePreloader is
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderTIFF
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderGIF
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderJPEG
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderBMP
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEMF
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderEPS
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.imageio.PreloaderImageIO
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.PreloaderRawPNG

So if I mush together the various jars with the assembly plugin, only one of the relevant service files will survive - in this case it looks like the latter one.

Have you tried run this with debug level enabled, and check if the ImageImplRegistry'sregisterPreloader method reports also the org.apache.fop.image.loader.batik.PreloaderSVG class in both cases?

I've pasted in a minimal example below, it will need files called img.png, img.tiff and img.svg in the current directory. You don't use the current directory for resources. They should be under the src/main/resources folder. You want something like: try (ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(Mavenproject2.class.getResourceAsStream("/x.svg"))) { ... }

@goose in the spirit of 'minimal example' I didn't do that. My original program used getResourceAsStream exactly as you suggest and the behavior is the same.

OK. My comment is more of a general one and relating to your 'can't load from jar' problem. As it happens, I'm guessing that fop won't support svg, which could be the reason for your immediate problem. You'd probably need Batik somewhere in there

Batik is a dependency and I've checked it's included in the jar/classpath. I think I might have found the reason, see my [edit2] at the bottom.

This issue is due to the fact that there are two libraries (fop-core-2.10.jar and xmlgraphics-common-2.10.jar) that contain the same spi files in the META-INF/services files, precisely:

org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageConverter
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImageLoaderFactory
org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.spi.ImagePreloader

Using the maven-assembly-plugin leads to have only the copy from one of the two libraries to be written into the final jar.
I suggest you to replace the assembly whit the maven-shade-plugin that instead can merge / append the contents of matching files, like this:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.6.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

Take a look also to the documentation page (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer) and also this other question (maven Assembly plugin is not appending/merging META-INF/services/ spi.AutoDiscoverable).
